What does "что" mean in the proverb "Людская молва — что морская волна"?
I don't understand the use of "что" in this proverb found in some dictionary. I read it like: "Людская молва - морская волна." or like: "Людская молва - как морская волна." or like: ""Людская молва - какая-то морская волна." but it is because I don't know what to do with "что" here.

In this example, что is a conjunction meaning "like, similar to" (see meaning 2 in Wiktionary). In this meaning, что is only used in grand style discourse (poetry, speeches, proverbs and similar).


Закон что дышло: куда повернёшь, туда и вышло.
Материнский гнев — что весенний снег: и много его выпадет, да скоро растает.
Лоб что лопата, а ума небогато.


Note that  Wiktionary is wrong about this expression being "colloquial" (разговорный).
It's widely used in folk poetry and imitations thereof:


Мужик что бык: втемяшится
В башку какая блажь —
Колом её оттудова
Не выбьешь...
[Некрасов, Кому на Руси жить хорошо]


It's a hallmark specifically of Russian poetry (as opposed to Church Slavonic). People tend to confuse "colloquial", "vernacular", "poetic", "old", and "dialectal", which sometimes spills to dictionaries.
Still, it's far from being colloquial. Its usage emphasizes the fact that the comparison being made is a poetic metaphor or a simile. It's not used (and has never been used) in this meaning in plain speech.

Thank you very much! On Wiktionary this meaning is said to be "нар.-поэт. и разг." What you wrote confirms that its use is "нар.-поэт." but seems in contradiction with "разг.". How should we understand that it is разговорное?

@Bruno: see the update

Thank you for the precision! I think it weird to confuse "poetic" and "colloquial" because they seem quite the opposite (we usually don't speak as in poetry).

@Bruno: this construction is used almost exclusively in folklore, along with втемяшится,  какая (instead of какая-нибудь), оттудова etc., which are colloquialisms indeed, deliberately used by Nekrasov. People just tend to clump it all together under the umbrella category of "weird stuff they use in the folklore".

You are correct in your assumption - 'что' in this instance equates to 'same as ~'.
It also sounds like an outdated way to state comparison in Russian, unless the sentence continues, it just sounds off on its own.

Thank you! It is unclear to me what you mean by "unless the sentence continues". Maybe examples could clarify it.

Of course. For example - 'Людская молва, что морская волна, пошумит, пошумит, да стихнет'. If you using the proverb to support a statement, or as a metaphor, it sounds fine. On its own (though I heard it before) it sounds off.

Thank you for the example! You could probably improve your answer in incorporating the example of your comment in the answer itself. Nevertheless, unless I misunderstood you, it seems that your answer slightly contradicts Quassnoi's answer: are you saying that a sentence like "Людская молва, что морская волна, пошумит, пошумит, да стихнет" is colloquial?
